# AC_FL_Runcontent is not defined , Exadel Fiji

Tags: jsf

I am using Exadel-Fiji 1.0, Richfaces 3.3.3, Jboss 4.3 -EAP, Seam 2.1.0, JSF-1.2_09

When I try to render a exadel fiji line chart , the page just throws up a blank screen and

the firefox error console says

AC_FL_Runcontent is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had the following code in my web.xml. I had to comment it out to get it working

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
  <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

This script error is because one of the fiji related js file is missing in your jsf page. Please add the following script in your xhtml/jsf page to resolve this issue:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/[your-application-context-name]/a4j/g/3_3_1.CR1com/exadel/fiji/renderkit/html/AC_OETags.js.jsf" />
```

Before testing this in your application, please check that you are able to view Javascript with your browser using the following URL:

```
http://[url]:8080/[your-application-context-name]/a4j/g/3_3_1.CR1com/exadel/fiji/renderkit/html/AC_OETags.js.jsf
```

or

```
http://[url]:8080/your-application-context-name/a4j/g/3_3_1.CR1com/exadel/fiji/renderkit/html/AC_OETags.js
```

If you are able to see the script content in your browser, your problem has been resolved, and there will be no need to comment the `web.xml` changes.